# Pause Program and Resume it when a key is hit

Tags: lua

I would like to know what code would pause a program and cause it to resume when "Enter" key is hit.

I am really new to Lua so i dont know very much yet.

Answer (score 1):

`local input_string = io.read()` for console applications

Comment: If your only purpose is to pause the script, i.e. you don't need what the user types when the script is paused, then you can strip the `local input_string =` part and simply write `io.read()`.